# SSIS: How to export more than 4000 characters to Excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have the following basic setup in SQL 2008 R2. This does not work however as I always get the errors

```
Error   1   Validation error. SQL to XLS: SQL to XLS: Columns "Original" and "messages" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.   Package.dtsx    0   0   
Error   2   Validation error. SQL to XLS Excel Destination [89]: Columns "Original" and "messages" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.    Package.dtsx    0   0
```

[image]

[image]

When I change it to be unicode the max is 4000 but I need it to be more because, well, I have more than 4000. Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried numerous solutions, but I just get errors.
then I try this.
It is easy to load 4000 characters of data into Excel by executing it with a shell script.

```
Exec Master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from [master].[dbo].[temptable]" queryout "E:\new.xlsx" -T -c'
```

you can run it in sql.